# Programming Phoenix: undefined function page_path/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having an issue with my web app with a compile error below:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/auth.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/auth.ex:49: undefined function page_path/2
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

I know most issues have been to do with missing routes on the `router.ex`, but it doesn't look like there is any issues here:

```
  scope "/", Rumbl do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/users/:id", UserController, :show
    resources "/users", UserController, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
    resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:new, :create, :delete]
    resources "/videos", VideoController

  end

  scope "/manage", Rumbl do
    pipe_through [:browser, :authenticate_user]

    resources "/videos", VideoController
  end
```

My web.ex looks like this:

```
def router do
  quote do
    use Phoenix.Router
    import Rumbl.Auth, only: [authenticate_user: 2] # New import
  end
end

def controller do
  quote do
    use Phoenix.Controller

    alias Rumbl.Repo
    import Ecto
    import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 1, from: 2]

    import Rumbl.Router.Helpers
    import Rumbl.Gettext
    import Rumbl.Auth, only: [authenticate_user: 2] # New import

  end
end
```

auth.ex looks like this

```
defmodule Rumbl.Auth do
  import Plug.Conn
  import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [checkpw: 2, dummy_checkpw: 0]
  import Phoenix.Controller
  alias Rumbl.Router.Helpers

  def init(opts) do
    Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
  end

  def call(conn, repo) do
    user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)
    user = user_id && repo.get(Rumbl.User, user_id)
    assign(conn, :current_user, user)
  end

  def login_by_username_and_pass(conn, username, given_pass, opts) do
    repo = Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
    user = repo.get_by(Rumbl.User, username: username)

    cond do
      user && checkpw(given_pass, user.password_hash) ->
        {:ok, login(conn, user)}
      user ->
        {:error, :unauthorized, conn}
      true ->
        dummy_checkpw()
        {:error, :not_found, conn}
    end
  end

  def login(conn, user) do
    conn
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
  end

  def logout(conn) do
    configure_session(conn, drop: true)
  end

  def authenticate_user(conn, _opts) do
    if conn.assigns.current_user do
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in to access that page")
      |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
      |> halt()
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you post auth.ex file? It seems there is an issue in it on line 49.

#### Solution:

Please change this line:

```
|> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))
```

to

```
|> redirect(to: Helpers.page_path(conn, :index))
```

Comment: I've added it above.

Comment: Please change this line
`|> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :index))`
to
`|> redirect(to: Helpers.page_path(conn, :index))`

Comment: this error came from generated files. why is this happening?

Comment: It is because of Router Helpers Alias

Answer (score 19):

In phoenix 1.4 you need to call the function with module name

```
Routes.page_path(@conn, :create)
```

Comment: Thx. Looking at some older tutorial and this fixed the issue cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, works for "topic_path"    |> redirect(to: Routes.topic_path(conn, :index)) too.