# How to resolve lib/.../views/user_view.ex:16: undefined function user_path/3 compilation error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Trying to add a User-View and User controller but I'm getting a strange compilation error.

From looking at [Programming Phoenix: undefined function page_path/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449151/programming-phoenix-undefined-function-page-path-2) I suspect it's also something to do with the generated files but I still don't understand how to resolve it

this is my user_controller.ex in the controller folder:

```
defmodule ChatterWeb.UserController do
  use ChatterWeb, :controller
  alias Chatter.User

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Repo.all(User)
    render(conn, "index.html", users: users)
  end
end
```

this is my user_view.ex in the views folder:

```
defmodule ChatterWeb.UserView do
  use ChatterWeb, :view
end
```

this is the routing section in my router.ex:

```
  scope "/", ChatterWeb do
    pipe_through :browser
    resources "/users", UserController
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end
```

this is my user.ex (which has the schema):

```
defmodule Chatter.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :encrypt_pass, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:email, :password])
    |> validate_required([:email, :password])
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
  end
end
```

And this is the error I get when compiling:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/chatter_web/views/user_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/chatter_web/views/user_view.ex:16: undefined function user_path/3
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:107: :elixir_locals."-ensure_no_undefined_local/3-lc$^0/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:107: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:208: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

I don't understand why is says `ex:16` if the file only has 3 lines of code. I'm guessing the `use` keyword injects the code from a different file, but that makes it really difficult to pinpoint where exactly it's going wrong.

Comment: By changing the name user to userp in the user_controller, router, and user_view file, everything works. however the moment i change the name of the templates file from user to userp, then i get the error of `== Compilation error in file lib/chatter_web/views/user_view.ex ==` so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the rendering at the controller (i think)

Comment: tbh this still doesn't resolve anything, i just get another error saying `Could not render "index2.html" for ChatterWeb.UserView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "lib/chatter_web/templates/user". No templates were compiled for this module.` when I visit `localhost:4000/users` and of course naming the file properly leads me back to the previous error

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `ex:16` in `lib/chatter_web/views/user_view.ex:16` actually refers to `lib/chatter_web/templates/user/index.html.eex`. I don't understand why. But in that file I refer to user_path(@conn, :show, user) when it should be Routes.user_path(@conn, :show, user). Learned this from [Undefined [controller]_path for route with two params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812524/undefined-controller-path-for-route-with-two-params) (I believe it is due to 1.4.3 documentation)

Comment: Thanks to @Schrockwell, "View modules actually take the `.eex` files and wrap them up as plain old functions in the module with the magic of macros. In addition to any functions you define in the module. So that’s why the line numbers are wonky… they’re referring to Elixir syntax that’s being generated at compile-time"